# Particle info node is not working for molecular add on in cycle ;(

Tags: particles, shader-nodes, particle-nodes

[image]

I want to make a sand block.

So, I followed youtube video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bdmVfwXIBhQ&t=324s

I made a good sand using molecular add on, but I had a problem in particle info node.

This is the picture that I wanted to have:

[image]

But This is what I had:

[image]

It is all black.

this is the texture I used

[image]

I need your help. ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [*Particle Info* node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/particle_info.html) works only in Cycles.

In the first screenshot, the viewport shading (<kbd>Z</kbd>) is set to *Rendered* (and the render engine is Cycles)
=> the node works.

But in the 2nd screenshot, the viewport shading is set to *Material Preview* (which is similar to Eevee)
 => the node does not work.

[image: screenshot 1]
<sup>Viewport shading *Rendered* (Cycles)</sup>

As you can see here the node works in *Rendered* mode (Cycles) but there is another problem. There is no real randomness. There is only the green area visible.

This is because the scalar *Random* value (R) is used for the *Vector* which is a vector (X, Y, Z). Blender will convert like this (1) => (1, 1, 1), (2) => (2, 2, 2) and so on. These vectors are not random, because it's always R=X=Y=Z. You probably want something like (2, 5, 1), (8, 4, 7), etc.

With help of the *Object Info* node and a 4D *White Noise* node you can get better random values and make it work in Eevee and Cycles. The random value is used for the *W* input and this will generate a true random vector (X, Y, Z) where all components are random.

[image: screenshot 2]
<sup>Viewport shading *Rendered* (Eevee)</sup>

Comment: if you want to use "particle info" in eevee i can recommend using animation-nodes. There is such an info node which gives you the information in EEVEE too.